# How to configure Root-level cascading values with IsFixed in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I follow [link from ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#root-level-cascading-values) to try Root-level cascading values but still cannot understand w

first option: >> work fine

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue("abc", s=>new CurrentSeasonModel { SelectedStageId = 65 });
```

On component

```
[CascadingParameter(Name ="abc")]
public CurrentSeasonModel? hehe{ get; set; }
```

2nd option: **to use isFixed**

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue("abc", s =>
{
    var currentSeason = new CurrentSeasonModel { SelectedStageId = 65 };
    var source = new CascadingValueSource<CurrentSeasonModel>(currentSeason, isFixed: true);
    return source;
});
```

On Component:

```
   [CascadingParameter(Name ="abc")]
    public CurrentSeasonModel? hehe{ get; set; }   >> fails to work, always null
```

I can't find anywhere to discuss about this.

**Updated:**

It turns out builder.Services.AddCascadingValue has 3 overloading methods, so I should only use the one without cascading name

```
 builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(s =>
{
    var currentSeason = new CurrentSeasonModel { SelectedStageId = 65 };
    var source = new CascadingValueSource<CurrentSeasonModel>(currentSeason, isFixed: true);
    return source;
});
```

Still, I wonder how to use the cascading name in Cascading Name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CascadingValueSource` has a constructor that includes the name

```cs
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(s =>
{
    var currentSeason = 
        new CurrentSeasonModel { SelectedStageId = 65 };

    return new CascadingValueSource<CurrentSeasonModel>(
            "abc",
            currentSeason,
            isFixed: true);
});
```

CascadingValueSource [Source Code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/CascadingValueSource.cs,5f9348362105fe50,references)

Comment: my bad, didn't know that. thanks.

Comment: do you know how to change its value from components and still persist the value through other components